# passing php variables between different pages that are linked trough anouther page

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP world, 
what I'm trying to do is to send 3 variables from lets say *example.php* to next page *example1.php* and the same variables to the third page *example3.php*,

the problem for me is, when posting them in `$_POST` they are visible in example1.php and I assign them to the another variables and again post them to the example3.php by $_POST 
and this is how do I redirect between pages not by send form method="post"

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=0;url=example1.php>";
```

and in the second form I send them in method="post"

what I have tried is using Cookies however it does not work everytime, on every browser, when the user clicks the 'back' button and enters new entries the old ones are still stored and so on,

someone had suggested to send them on the URL by `$_GET` , but I'm sending sensitive data.

My application is a mail registration for external entity that connects to database that is outsourced ( example.php ) if validation is complete and correct, the variables are sent to the other page ( example1.php ) where the user puts his email and password, and in the the third ( example3.php ) all the settings entered are processed, so I cannot get the data from first page to the last.

Comment: *someone have suggested to send them un the URL by $_GET , but I'm sending sensitive data*. *Post* is in no way anymore secure than *get*.

Comment: This is exactly what the HTTP/1.1 307 [redirect code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) is for - a 307 redirect should repeat the original request **with the same method** to a new URI. However, it looks to me as if [sessions](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) are what you are looking for here.

Comment: Are all of the pages on the same domain? If so you can just use a php session to store data between requests: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: @Yoshi not entirely true. This is mainly because query strings are often logged in the web server's request log, and as a result sending (for example) passwords as a GET parameter is a bad idea. Although it is true that POST is no less susceptible to things like man-in-the-middle attacks than GET.

Comment: There're possible ways to do that. 1. If by any means, you can store the data in database since they're sensitive. 2. If you do not what to using POST or GET, there 's another option that you can use $_SESSION  to store provided that your data is not too long.

Comment: @DaveRandom *... no less susceptible to things like man-in-the-middle attacks than GET* - That's basically what I meant.

Comment: @Thavarith So when i do a session, can i use it in the third page, well i have tried that think but it didnt work with me i'll try it again an get back to you, thank you for the fast replies,

Comment: Okay, let's me write you some codes here, i will post the answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try with following codes:

```
/** example.php */
 * You must put on the very first line of you page
 */
<?php session_start(); ?>

// These codes can be anywhere after the above
<?php 
    $_SESSION['varName1'] = 'Value 1';
    $_SESSION['varName2'] = 'Value 2';
    $_SESSION['varName3'] = 'Value 3';

    // You can test to see the result here:
    echo 'varName1 Value: '.$_SESSION['varName1'].'<br />';
    echo 'varName2 Value: '$_SESSION['varName2'].'<br />';
    echo 'varName3 Value: '$_SESSION['varName3'].'<br />';
    // You can print anywhere after here or 
    // you can update their values up to you.
?>


/** example1.php */
 * You must put on the very first line of you page
 */
<?php session_start(); ?>

// These codes can go anywhere in your page after above line
<?php   
    // You can print the 3 values from example.php
    echo 'varName1 Value: '.$_SESSION['varName1'].'<br />';
    echo 'varName2 Value: '$_SESSION['varName2'].'<br />';
    echo 'varName3 Value: '$_SESSION['varName3'].'<br />';
    // You can print anywhere after here or 
    // you can update their values up to you.
?>


/** example2.php */
 * You must put on the very first line of you page
 */
<?php session_start(); ?>

// These codes can go anywhere in your page after above line
<?php   
    // You can print the 3 values from example.php, example2.php
    echo 'varName1 Value: '.$_SESSION['varName1'].'<br />';
    echo 'varName2 Value: '$_SESSION['varName2'].'<br />';
    echo 'varName3 Value: '$_SESSION['varName3'].'<br />';
    // You can print anywhere after here or 
    // you can update their values up to you.
?>
```

Comment: This is not fully coded for using PHP session. You may need to set `session_name()`, `session_id()` in order to store and retrieve back. The code above could be some clues for you with session in php. Some more you need to check session variables using `isset()` function for all `$_SESSION` variables..and so on.

Comment: Note that using php session, it will create a single file(.txt) store your web server so every time you make request starting with `session_start()` it will trigger the server to open session file and store on global variable `$_SESSION`. You may find more info here: [PHP SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) or [SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: #Thavarith Thank you for the great Guide,
I would like to tell you that your guide made it work, and using 
session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_start();

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the best  way is to use [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) variables

on page 1

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['yourvariable'] = 'foo';
```

on page 2

```
session_start();
$foo = $_SESSION['yourvariable'];//$foo = 'foo';
```